# Is there a way to change the iterator of the for loop?

Tags: python, for-loop

I'm reading a file line per line in a for loop and do a while loop modifying the loop for iterator like bellow:

```
for line in archive:
    ...
    if re.search("{",line):
        while not re.search("}",line):
          ...
          line = next_line
    ...
```

Complete code bellow

```
import re

a = ["{\n","int b,c,d\n","#pragma omp parallel for\n","for (int i=0;i<10;i++)\n",'1\n','2\n','3\n','\n4',"}\n",'6','7','8','9','0','z','y']
listwh=[]
a_it=iter(a)
text =[]
flagcb=0
for j in a:
  print(j)
for line in a_it:  
  if re.search("{",line):

     flagcb=flagcb+line.count("{")-line.count("}")
     while(flagcb>0):
         listwh.append(line)
         print(flagcb)
         print(line)
         flagcb=flagcb+line.count("{")-line.count("}")
         line = next(a_it)
  text.append(line)  

for i in listwh:
  print(i)
print("\ninterval\n")
#for i in text:
#  print(i)
```

I like to stay in the while loop until the stop condition which deppends of the archive read.

Comment: Voting to reopen, though I believe Ry- has the right answer in the community wiki.

Answer (score 2):

You can create an iterator from your iterable explicitly:

```
archive_iter = iter(archive)
```

Then it’ll stay advanced between loops.

```
for line in archive_iter:
    if '{' in line:
        while '}' not in line:
            line = next(archive_iter)
```

Comment: i've tried your solution using archive_iter=iter(archive) before the for loop
but in the atribution of next it not works

Comment: the stop iteration did not occured i put a print into the while loop and printed all after the line which have the curly bracket

Comment: @ReinaldoFilho: You mean a `print` inside the while loop printed a line containing `}`?

Comment: exactly, and printed after the while condition of stop, until the overflow of the list

Comment: @ReinaldoFilho: That… really shouldn’t be possible :D Can you show the code with the `print` included?

Comment: I understand, I've edited the post, please show me my mistake.

Comment: @ReinaldoFilho: So that prints `flagcb` instead of the line. What’s its output and what do you expect instead?

Comment: I expect only print under curly brackets i dont want to see 1-0,z,y